# Modify $request_uri in Nginx

Tags: nginx

I have multiple apps running on the `Nginx` server:

```
http://example.com/app1/ctrl/view
http://example.com/app2/ctrl/view
...
```

I would like to assign these apps DNS like so:

```
http://app1.example.com
http://app2.example.com
...
```

For that I've tried the following server block:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name app1.example.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://example.com/app1/$request_uri;
        }
}
```

If a user is not logged in, my app would redirect to URI:

```
app1/ctrl/user/login?_next=/app/ctrl/view
```

Essentially `$request_uri` becomes (Note doubled *app1* instance):

```
app1/app1/ctrl/user/login?_next=/app/ctrl/view
```

Is there a convenient way to modify `$request_uri` or a better method to get around this problem?

***EDIT1***

It seems I've solved my problem with the following server block:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name app1.example.com;

        location / {

            set $new_request_uri $request_uri;

            if ($request_uri ~ ^/app1/(.+)$) {
                set $new_request_uri $1;
            }

            proxy_pass http://example.com/app1/$new_request_uri;
        }
}
```

If someone knows a better (or proper "`Nginx`") way to do this please don't hesitate to post an answer.

***EDIT2***

Based on the comments I've also tried the following:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name app1.example.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://example.com/app1/;
            proxy_redirect /app1/ /;
        }

        location ~ ^/app1/(.+)$ {
            return 301 http://$server_name/$1;
        }
}
```

This one looks better on screen, as it eliminates *app1* instance in the `$request_uri` part completely, but you must have two `location` blocks.

***EDIT3***

The most efficient way to solve my problem apparently is as shown in this config:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name app1.example.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://example.com/app1/;
            proxy_redirect /app1/ /;
        }

        location /app1/ {
            rewrite ^/app1(.+) $1 permanent;
        }
}
```

This is due to the fact, that `Nginx` always tries to match the longest `prefix` first and then (if `^~` modifier is not present) starts sequentially processing `regexes` until the first `regex match` is found. Essentially this means that all `regexes` are processed on every request, regardless if any of these find a match, therefore it's better to have `regexes` inside `location` directives.

Comment: Very nice to see the updates and all the solutions. A way around `nginx` always finding the most specific location is using exact matches with `=`.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to go complex way. Solution is much simpler

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name app1.example.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://app1.example.com/app1/;
        }

        location /app1/ {
            proxy_pass http://app1.example.com/app1/;
            # or
            # rewrite ^/app1(.+) $1 permanent;
        }
}
```

Nginx will take care of adding `/app1/` to request and strip it from `Location` header.

See [proxy_redirect](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_redirect) directive.

Comment: Thanks for the tip :) But my own resolution works better, as it doesn't break when user tries to visit either `http://.../app1/ctrl/user/login` nor `http://.../ctrl/user/login`. You see, my problem is that apps not only redirect via `Location` but sometimes specific action lives under the FQDN, like logout is behind `http://.../app1/ctrl/user/logout` which is hardcoded into the urls on the website...

Comment: In that case I would just add another location. See update

Comment: Yep, pretty much the same what I've figured out on my *EDIT2* :) BTW, according to the `Nginx` docs, `rewrites` should be replaced with `returns` where possible. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, you moved regexp from rewrite to location. That's worse, because now nginx have to check regexp on every request. So, instead of blindly following to docs, you should understand why docs says so. But anyway, the difference will be practical only in case of really huge number of request

Comment: this breaks if you need to `set` the upstream with your own `resolver`. probably not the long term choice for a cloud native application